# Internal site works External site gets "Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql

Our sharepoint works great on our internal network. We use Sharepoint 2013 and SQLEXPRESS 2012.  We have a domain intranet.crkoes.org that we have setup but get this error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a
>   server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from
>   the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm,
>   use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start
>   menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation
>   can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by
>   users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the
>   configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use
>   the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start
>   menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: This operation can be performed only on a
>   computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions
>   in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this
>   server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration
>   Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010
>   Products.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.AlternateServerUrlFromHttpRequestUrl(Uri
>   url) +283
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext
>   ctx) +400
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext
>   context) +1144
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current() +200
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
>   site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken
>   appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout,
>   Boolean bAsAnonymous) +400
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode
>   authenticationMode) +120
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny() +412
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32
>   compatibilityLevel) +39
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
>   +106    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
>   +131    Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   app) +947
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +597
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +328
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +394
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +418
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): This operation can be performed only on a
>   computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions
>   in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this
>   server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration
>   Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010
>   Products.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +678
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +810
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280

We are unable to create a new admin user in the management studio.

Comment: did you check the permission on the farm admin and other services account in SQL...if they have right permission on config db

Comment: Would this be checked in the SQL management studio?

Comment: yes, also check if the SQL Server Service is running?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in SharePoint 2016, We were able to fix it.

It turns out some how the SharePoint Farm admin account lost permissions on Allow Logon Locally and Local Administrator and logon as service.

Once making sure those permissions were restored. The Central administration was up and running after the Reboot.